# Getting "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error" when calling a webserver using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, web-services

I'm trying to call a webservice using ajax. The web service is written in vb.net. When I call it directly using it's url it works fine, but when I use ajax to call it it returns

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error-http://localhost/chart/webService.asmx/HelloWorld.

Here is my webservice code:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class webService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

End Class
```

and here is javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var webMethod = 'http://localhost/chart/webService.asmx/HelloWorld';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webMethod,
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('all good');
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('err');
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

I changed HelloWorld() to the following code but still getting the same error:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Dim aa As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    Return aa.Serialize("Hello World")
End Function
```

Comment: your function *hello_world" is not returning json object.

Comment: Updated may post. But still getting error

Comment: have you tried accessing it in the browser?

Comment: Yes. It works fine when I access it in browser

Comment: how about error logs - 500 usually indicates that it's internal error,  make your serverside  code dump logs, if it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
data:{},
```

instead of:

```
data:"{}",
```